# Codeigniter 3.0 works on localhost but not server

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have set up a CI 3 app on localhost (MAMP) and it works fine but when I upload it to the server (Ubuntu 12.04 LAMP) it shows 404 error page. The issue is not with the server configuration because when I upload CI 2.1.4 it works fine. There are no errors in the php error log.

I am using apache2 and php5.5.11

Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: is the HTML for the 404 error the default error message from Apache?

Comment: Nope. It is codeigniter 404 error page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It the damn capitalization issue! In CI 3 you must keep all your controllers, models and god knows what else capitalized!

Answer (score 2):

[As Abdullah's answer notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23546991/codeigniter-3-0-works-on-localhost-but-not-server/23547505#23547505), you have to put the capital letter in front of the file name to make them work. Windows has no problems at all since they don't use case sensitive naming as linux/unix do. So as incredible this can sound, if your Windows XAMPP localhost server is working and when you upload it to a Linux/Unix XAMPP and you keep getting 404 errors, try the capital letter first, that could save you some time.